# How to unit test code consuming gcloud storage?

Tags: go

I want to write unit test for the below code

```
package main

import (
    "context"

    "google.golang.org/api/option"
    "cloud.google.com/go/storage"
)

var (
    NewClient = storage.NewClient
)

func InitializeClient(ctx context.Context) (*storage.Client, error) {
    credFilePath := "Storage credentials path."

    // Creates a client.
    client, err := NewClient(ctx, option.WithCredentialsFile(credFilePath))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return client, nil
}

func createStorageBucket(ctx context.Context, client *storage.Client, bucketName string) (*storage.BucketHandle, error) {

    // Sets your Google Cloud Platform project ID.
    projectID := "Some project id"

    // Creates a Bucket instance.
    bucket := client.Bucket(bucketName)

    // Creates the new bucket.
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Second*10)
    defer cancel()
    if err := bucket.Create(ctx, projectID, nil); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return bucket, nil
}

func bucketExists(ctx context.Context, client *storage.Client, bucketName string) error {
    bucket := client.Bucket(bucketName)
    if _, err := bucket.Attrs(ctx); err != nil {
        //try creating the bucket
        if _, err := createStorageBucket(ctx, client, bucketName); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    ctx = context.Background()
    client, err := InitializeClient(ctx)
    bucketName := "Some bucket name"
    err = bucketExists(ctx, client, bucketName)
}
```

bucket.Create() and bucket.Attrs() are http calls, also Bucket(), Object() and NewReader() returning structs(So in my sense there is no meaning of implement interface for this use case)

Note: storage.NewClient() is also http call but i am avoiding external call using monkey pathching approch in my test by providing custom implementaion.

```
var (
    NewClient = storage.NewClient
)
```

Comment: if your client would expose a method such as `GetReader(ctx context.Context, bucket, object string) io.ReadCloser` things would be easy. (though not sure what it does actually return)

Comment: What is the purpose of such a test? You'd be testing a remote service, which isn't really a unit test.

Comment: @mh-cbon It returns a struct of type *storage.Writer.

Comment: can you give it a try and edit your question with your attempts and report what failed in your opinion.

Comment: @Flimzy  i am not doing any service call. I am using monkey patching to achive this
eg: 
```
var NewClient = storage.NewClient
```
Since New client is exposed at package level, i can assing my own function in my test.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question, though. What is the purpose of this test? What would cause it to fail? What do you hope to learn when it passes?

Comment: I hope updated code snipet will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is so thin that is is hard to figure how to test that.

I guess Flimzy grasped that reading at the title.

There is a fundamental misunderstanding because of/in the title `How to write unit test for gcloud storage?`.

Well we should not. They did it. A better title would be `How to unit test code consuming gcloud storage?` I am not trying to be picky here, but explains what i understood trying to solve that question.

So anyways, this whole thing lead me to write less thin code, so that i can test that the code i write, the lines driving the storage, did what we expect it does.

This whole thing is so convoluted and out of tin air that I dont think it will answer your question.

but anyways, if that helps thinking about this difficulty that is already a win.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "testing"
    "time"

    "cloud.google.com/go/storage"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

type client struct {
    c         *storage.Client
    projectID string
}

func New() client {
    return client{}
}

func (c *client) Initialize(ctx context.Context, projectID string) error {
    credFilePath := "Storage credentials path."
    x, err := NewClient(ctx, option.WithCredentialsFile(credFilePath))
    if err == nil {
        c.c = x
        c.projectID = projectID
    }
    return err
}

func (c client) BucketExists(ctx context.Context, bucketName string) bool {
    if c.c == nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("not initialized")
    }
    bucket := c.c.Bucket(bucketName)
    err := bucket.Attrs(ctx)
    return err == nil
}

func (c client) CreateBucket(ctx context.Context, bucketName string) (*storage.BucketHandle, error) {
    if c.c == nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("not initialized")
    }
    bucket := c.c.Bucket(bucketName)
    err := bucket.Create(ctx, c.projectID, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return bucket, err
}

func (c client) CreateBucketIfNone(ctx context.Context, bucketName string) (*storage.BucketHandle, error) {
    if !c.BucketExists(bucketName) {
        return c.CreateBucket(ctx, c.projectID, bucketName)
    }
    return c.c.Bucket(bucketName), nil
}

type clientStorageProvider interface { // give it a better name..
    Initialize(ctx context.Context, projectID string) (err error)
    CreateBucketIfNone(ctx context.Context, bucketName string) (*storage.BucketHandle, error)
    CreateBucket(ctx context.Context, bucketName string) (*storage.BucketHandle, error)
    BucketExists(ctx context.Context, bucketName string) bool
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    cmd := flag.Arg(0)
    projectID := flag.Arg(1)
    bucketName := flag.Arg(2)

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*10)
    defer cancel()

    client := New()

    if cmd == "create" {
        createBucket(ctx, client, projectID, bucketName)
    } else {
        // ... more
    }
}

// this is the part we are going to test.
func createBucket(ctx context.Context, client clientStorageProvider, projectID, bucketName string) error {
    err := client.Initialize(ctx, projectID)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return client.CreateBucketIfNone(bucketName)
  // maybe we want to apply retry strategy here,
  // and test that the retry was done;
}

type clientFaker struct {
    initErr         error
    createErr       error
    createIfNoneErr error
    bucketExistsErr error
}

func (c clientFaker) Initialize(ctx context.Context, projectID string) (err error) {
    return c.initErr
}
func (c clientFaker) CreateBucketIfNone(ctx context.Context, bucketName string) (*storage.BucketHandle, error) {
    return nil, c.createIfNoneErr
}
func (c clientFaker) CreateBucket(ctx context.Context, bucketName string) (*storage.BucketHandle, error) {
    return nil, c.createErr
}
func (c clientFaker) BucketExists(ctx context.Context, bucketName string) bool {
    return nil, c.bucketExistsErr
}

func TestCreateBucketWithFailedInit(t *testing.T) {
    c := clientFaker{
        initErr: fmt.Errorf("failed init"),
    }
    ctx := context.Background()
    err := createBucket(ctx, c, "", "")
    if err == nil {
        t.Fatalf("should have failed to initialize the bucket")
    }
}

// etc...
```

note that i am not happy having `*storage.BucketHandle` as a return parameter, too specific, but i had no use of it (i put it here because it was there, otherwise hanging), so it was hard to design something around that.

note², it might happen my code is not fully compilable. I am having a dependency problem that i don t want to fix now and it prevent me from seeing all errors (it stops too early in the process)

Comment: So basically write a wrapper for required cloud storage api's, write a consumer method to consume the wrapper and write test for consumer.

Comment: @user3453324 if you have further questions or example i am interesting to read about it.